# How can I change the Slug URL in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I would like to change the Slug URL as follows:

```
- blogger.com/2016/08/title.html
+ blogger.com/title.html
```

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to have the Slug without a date.

[image]

Source: [Google Products Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/blogger/w5sBWiSpt5Q)